# Is there a faster way to do something like this html tag creating function?

Tags: php, html

My friend and I who is a bit of a newbie like me were discussing writing a PHP function to do some shorthand html..

For example:

```
function hf($tag,$var) {

    return '<' . $tag . '>' . $var . '</' . $tag . '>';

}

echo hf('h1','howdy');
```

Of course, this 'shortcut' actually takes longer to write in the end than just:

```
<h1>howdy</h1>
```

I think its still even longer than if in php having to type:

```
$var = '<h1>howdy</h1>';
```

But maybe starts becoming a little more closer to being a shortcut when doing something like:

```
$var = '<div>' . hf('h1','howdy') . '</div>';
```

But really - its not a shortcut at all. Maybe only on larger tags with 3 or more characters does it start becoming a teeny shortcut.

I thought though we would take it to the experts out there to see if you have thought of a 'shorthand' way of producing html while working in php.

I think textmates shorthand is pretty excellent ie:

```
h1. howdy
```

That seems to trump them all but I haven't seen a textmate serverside parser or something like that out there.

Have you got a faster method for doing this? My friend and I both agree that all this open and closing and forward slashes gets a bit tedious and its a bit like finger dancing sometimes when you're working in php handling doing all the apostrophes and fullstops also.

Comment: very short and to the point, your comment is :D

Comment: Something you might find usefull (and that I would recommend to defenitelly separate logic from presentational data) : http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: @yoda - thats interesting, cheers.

Comment: What about the tag attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "TextMate shorthand" you refer to is probably [Textile](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/), for which there is a good PHP parser (look for "Get Textile" in the right sidebar).

A similar lightweight markup language is [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), a version of which is used here on Stack Overflow, and for which there are several good PHP parsers like [this one](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

Finally there are languages like [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/) and [Jade](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php) that abstract away a lot of the repetition in HTML while providing a more complete templating featureset. Haml, too, has [PHP libraries](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/) available.

I usually end up writing Plain Old HTML, but when you want something a little (or a lot) tighter there are a lot of options.